# Is there a convention to denote effect size (like 1-3 stars for statistical significance)?

Tags: effect-size

The convention of using stars to denote statistical significance is widely known, so one star means p < 0.05, two stars p < 0.01 and three stars p < 0.001. Nevertheless, statistical significance does not inform directly about the effect size, which can be quantified e.g. with one of Cohen's coefficients. When such coefficient has a value = 0.2, the effect is considered small, large for value > 0.5, etc. I was wondering if, by analogy to p-values, there is a threshold-based convention to mark effect size? E.g. "x" for a small effect size, "xxx" for a large effect size, or something like that?

Comment: I've not encountered any such convention. But the whole point of quantifying effect size is, erm, to quantify effect size. Some kind of starring is just as backwards a step as starring P-values, indeed arguably even more so.

Comment: Hi Maciek. What would be the purpose of such a convention? Is your question just out of curiosity, or are you facing some problem that such a convention would supposedly solve? If it's the latter, then it can be a good idea to mention what this problem is exactly.

Comment: Hi @J-J-J. I was just preparing a plot, I added stars to it and, just to convey more information, wanted to add info about the effect size. I was thinking of using the same convention as stars for the p-value. But in fact I am convinced by Peter Flom's answer, so I guess I will remove the p-value stars instead.

Comment: So I guess you want to convey the relevance of the effect size (ES). You may have already thought about it, but if there are some specific thresholds relevant to your study, showing them in a way or another on the plot could be a good idea -- e.g. if you're studying the effect of a weight-loss drug over the course of several months, you might want to indicate thresholds of, say, 1kg, 3kg, and 5kg (or their translation as a Cohen's standardized effect size), and where the observed ES is located relative to them. It may be also interesting to plot a confidence interval around the observed ES.

Comment: If you don't have specific thresholds in mind, an alternative is to plot effect sizes observed in other similar studies (assuming it won't overload the plot or create other visualization problems). It allows readers to compare the effect size from your study to others, and might give you some additional ideas for future research.

Comment: @J-J-J There is no thresholds specific to my study. I just wanted to enrich the statistic significance information, with physiological significance quantified by effect size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, starring p values is a bad idea. Journals are, increasingly, not doing it. Precise p values (except for very, very small ones) are becoming more common (including when they are not sig.)

Second, the convention for which p values get how many stars is not so set in stone. The one you suggest is the most common, but I've seen others.

Third, the notions of "small", "medium", and "large" effect sizes aren't rules, they're more like guidelines (any Terry Pratchett fans out there?) and were never intended as anything more than that. In different contexts, the same effect size cold be small or large. For instance, in some areas of physics, r of 0.9 is disappointingly small. In some areas of psychology, it is so large that it is suspicious. IIRC, Cohen introduced those levels in his book on power analysis, where some sort of effect size is needed and researchers are often reluctant to supply one.